# How to create insert query across two tables where one table has foreign key in the second table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables:
1> Batch which has id and name columns
2> Trans which has id, batch_id and name columns

Basically for a given batch, there could be multiple Trans records.

I have one Batch record and 2 Trans records and would like to use SQL Batch Update to insert them in both tables where these records should bind using foreign key (batch_id).

## Batch

### id name

1 b1

## Trans

### id batch_id name

1  1 T1

My question is how to create the insert queries which does the inserts in these 2 tables as part of one batch operation.

Comment: Do you have a question? Because there isn't one above.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, just updated the question.

Comment: Sorry - still not clear. Why can't you just insert them? Wrap them in BEGIN ... COMMIT and they either all get added or don't.

Comment: @RichardHuxton If he is trying a Batch Update, it won't work because the primary key is unknown to the Trans table. He would need to do this in a transaction loop where he first inserts to Batch, gets the id, then inserts to Trans. Or he could devise a mechanism to generate the primary key ids before inserting. But I don't think a batch insert will handle this automatically.

Comment: But the example data clearly shows the IDs.

Comment: I agree it is not clear but I think he was just explaining the table structures.

Comment: thank you guys. Ricardo's response helped me!

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Postgre 9.1 you can do:

```
with rows as (
INSERT INTO Batch (name) VALUES ('b1') RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO Trans(batch_id, name)
SELECT id, 'T1'
FROM rows
INSERT INTO Trans(batch_id, name)
SELECT id, 'T2'
FROM rows
```

Comment: thanks Atanas. this is cool.